# Android Emulator will not start with eclipse JUNO

Tags: android, eclipse, eclipse-juno

I just installed the SDK for android and whenever I create a device in emulator, when i click start, i get the below error.

RAM 512
Device Nexus

```
Starting emulator for AVD 'blah'
Failed to create Context 0x3005
could not get wglGetExtensionsStringARB
emulator: WARNING: Could not initialize OpenglES emulation, using software renderer.
could not get wglGetExtensionsStringARB
could not get wglGetExtensionsStringARB
could not get wglGetExtensionsStringARB
could not get wglGetExtensionsStringARB
could not get wglGetExtensionsStringARB
could not get wglGetExtensionsStringARB
could not get wglGetExtensionsStringARB
```

I am on Windows 8.